# Azure, Python — Getting blocked from bing data

Tags: python, .net, azure

I'm running a Python app (flask framework) on an Azure platform. The program scrapes data from indeed.com and bing.com. I thought initially that bing was locking me out but I can run the program fine locally (on the same server as the web site) which suggests that bing hasn't locked me out. Plus, I've scraped *a lot* of data from bing with no problems, but when I run it on Azure I can only get a few data points and then I'm shut off.

Also, when I run this:

```
try:
    r = requests.head("http://www.bing.com/search?q=vanderbilt+university+nashville+tn")
    flask.flash(r.status_code)
except requests.ConnectionError:
    flask.flash("failed to connect")
    return self.get()
```

I get `200`, so I know it's not bing shutting me off.

This is my first time running on an Azure platform. My firm owns the server, so we have full authority to change things, I just don't know what to change to prevent Azure (or whatever the problem is) from shutting me out. How can I prevent this from happening? Does anyone else have experience with this?

I'm not completely sure that it's Azure, but I'm convinced that it's not bing.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by being shut out? What responses are you getting in Azure?

Comment: @selllikesybok, The program, when run on Azure, is not returning any bing data. It returns nothing, no error message.